# Предложение о верблюдах и их хозяевах

Tags: грамотная-речь, корректура, типы-ошибок

В одном из массовых журналов встретилась такая заметка ("Не подведи, верблюд!"):

*В столице ОАЭ Абу-Даби более 10 000 верблюдов из Бахрейна, Кувейта, Омана, Катара и Саудовской Аравии будут соревноваться за звание самого красивого "корабля пустыни". **Они предстанут перед экспертной комиссией, она и определит, владелец которого из них получит главный приз в 9,5 млн долларов.** Есть и другие призы...*

Информация предложения воспринимаема и понятна, но ощущается присутствие какого-то рассогласования. В чем же ошибка, нужна ли правка?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант редактирования:

**Животные предстанут перед экспертной комиссией, она и определит, чей владелец получит главный приз в 9,5 млн долларов.**

**Стилистические неточности**: повтор местоимений они, она, из них; союзное слово КОТОРОГО расположено на значительном расстоянии от "корабля пустыни".

Answer (score 1):

**Ошибка** - нагромождение местоимений: "**Они** предстанут перед экспертной комиссией, **она** и определит, владелец **которого** из **них** получит главный приз в 9,5 млн долларов."

Предлагаю правку:

**КОТОРОГО (ассоциируется со счётом) меняем на КАКОГО, два других  местоимения заменяем существительными.**

***Верблюды предстанут перед экспертной комиссией, которая и определит, владелец какого животного получит главный приз в 9,5 млн долларов.***

Comment: Интересно,  выражение "владелец какого животного" может иметь оттенок неопределенности? Возможно ли такое понимание, что речь идет о других животных, а не только о верблюдах? (Это вопрос к возможности замены "которого" на "какого", насколько это корректно).

Comment: Jasmin, в предложении говорится только о верблюдах, которые предстанут перед комиссией. Поэтому вряд ли у кого-то возникнет мысль о других животных.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, формально все правила согласования соблюдены. Не очень мне нравится тяжелое "владелец которого из них", я бы написал просто "владелец какого верблюда".